# Vb .Net 1.1 Grouping Arrays - Key/Value Pair

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm having a little issue in trying to achieve the following:

I have a Database table that contains documents, the table has the following columns:

DocumentName,
DocumentCategoryName,
DocumentDescription,

When the data is retrieved from the stored procedure I would like to group the results by DocumentCategoryName for example I have 3 data rows in this table two of the rows belong to the same documentCategoryname but have different DocumentNames and DocumentDescription, the third row has a different documentcategoryName and Documentname and DocumentDescription.

Desired outcome (as shown as below in a simple illustration)

```
{
 DocumentCategoryName:
           [
             Documentname,
             DocumentDescription
           ],
           [
             Documentname,
             DocumentDescription
           ]
DocumentCategoryName:
            [
             Documentname,
             DocumentDescription
           ]
}
```

The Code I have so far

```
     Dim documents As New SortedList
        Dim doc As New ArrayList

   If .DataReader.HasRows Then
                Do While .DataReader.Read
                    Attachment = New CottageAttachment(.strField("fileName"), .strField("name"), .strField("description"), .strField("fileNameForWeb"))
                    Dim categoryName As String = Attachment.DocumentCategoryName

                    If Not documents.ContainsKey(categoryName) Then
                        documents.Add(categoryName, New ArrayList)
                        doc.Add(Attachment.FileName)
                        doc.Add(Attachment.DocumentDescription)
                        doc.Add(Attachment.fileNameForWeb)
                    

                    End If

                    doc.Add(Attachment.FileName)
                    doc.Add(Attachment.DocumentDescription)
                    doc.Add(Attachment.fileNameForWeb)
           

                    'add document to category
                    DirectCast(documents(categoryName), ArrayList).Add(doc)




                    

                Loop
            End If
```

whats happening is that it's not doing the grouping correctly, outcome is shown below:

```
{
 DocumentCategoryName:
           [
             Documentname,
             DocumentDescription,
             Documentname,
             DocumentDescription,
              Documentname,
             DocumentDescription,
           ]
DocumentCategoryName:
            [
             Documentname,
             DocumentDescription,
               Documentname,
             DocumentDescription,
               Documentname,
             DocumentDescription,
           ]
}
```

Comment: Debug your code. Set a breakpoint at the top and step through the code line by line, examining the state at each step. As soon as the state is not what you expect, you have found an issue and you can examine that specifically. Even if you still can't fix it yourself, at least you can provide us with all the relevant information. If it never deviates from your expectations and it still doesn't work then it's your expectations that are the issue, so you need to reevaluate them, i.e. go back to the drawing board and work on an algorithm that isn't broken.

Comment: Based on the output, it looks like you're throwing all of the names and descriptions into one list, instead of making a list of items where each item is a list that contains the name and description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to resolve this in the end,  It was exactly what @Craig said,  My updated code is now:

```
 If .DataReader.HasRows Then
                Do While .DataReader.Read
                    Attachment = New CottageAttachment(.strField("DocumentTitle"), .strField("DocumentDescription"), .strField("CategoryName"), .strField("FileName"), .strField("Year"), .strField("CottageCode"))
                    Dim categoryName As String = Attachment.CategoryName

                    If Not documents.ContainsKey(categoryName) Then
                        documents.Add(categoryName, New ArrayList)



                    End If


                    'add document to category
                    DirectCast(documents(categoryName), ArrayList).Add(Attachment)






                Loop
            End If
            .CloseDataReader()
```